# How can I list posts dynamically using jquery and json api?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, wordpress

I want to retrieve posts from my site web with JSON API, and I tried more codes but no data displaying. Where is the problem? 
HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="searchPage"  >

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>News</h1>

</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="searchFood"></ul>   
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#searchPage", function(){
$.getJSON("http://www.maan-lagh.com/?json=get_recent_posts", function(data){
    var output = '';
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        output += '<li><a href="#">' + value.title + '</a></li>';
    });
    $('#searchFood').html(output).listview("refresh");
 });
});
```

Comment: Why does this have to do with Android or even Wordpress ?

Comment: I want to displaying posts from my site in my mobile app(android&ios)

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? The request is likely conflicting with the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). To get by this, the API will need to either specifically provide permission to your application via [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) or support alternate request methods like [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/).

Comment: no..no error. in my config.xml (Phonegap) i have putting this line <access origin="*"/> for permission mentioned in your comment.Jonathan Lonowski

Comment: i am sorry i have this error in my browser: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.maan-lagh.com/api/get_posts/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.